# Can't parse flashscore results using Selenium and Python from https://www.flashscore.com/

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to parse the list of selenium python without results. What I want is to remove the 0-0 results of soccer matches.
Example code:

```
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/match/Qs85KCdA/#h2h/overall")
time.sleep(3)

rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='h2h__row']")

for row in rows:
    results = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='h2h__regularTimeResult']")
    date = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='h2h__date']")
    print(results.text)
    print(date.text)
```

Output:

```
0 : 0
10.12.21
1 : 2
04.12.21
0 : 2
01.12.21
0 : 0
27.11.21
3 : 1
22.11.21
0 : 0
10.12.21
1 : 2
05.12.21
0 : 5
30.11.21
1 : 2
27.11.21
1 : 1
20.11.21
0 : 0
10.12.21
5 : 1
30.06.20
2 : 2
15.12.19
1 : 0
15.04.13
1 : 1
18.11.12
```

What i want is to don't print the 0:0. So if there is 0:0 result in the overall matche summary i don't print it. I've tried everything but nothing worked. Could someone help me?

Comment: Just string comparison the results.text?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the *0 : 0* results of soccer matches to extract the list of results of soccer matches using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) *Python* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/match/Qs85KCdA/#h2h/overall")
  results = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='h2h__regularTimeResult' and not(text()='0 : 0')]")))]
  dates = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='h2h__regularTimeResult' and not(text()='0 : 0')]//ancestor::div[1]/span[@class='h2h__date']")))]
  for i,j in zip(results, dates):
      print(f"{i} result was on {j}")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1 : 2 result was on 04.12.21
  0 : 2 result was on 01.12.21
  3 : 1 result was on 23.11.21
  1 : 2 result was on 06.12.21
  0 : 5 result was on 01.12.21
  1 : 2 result was on 27.11.21
  1 : 1 result was on 20.11.21
  5 : 1 result was on 30.06.20
  2 : 2 result was on 15.12.19
  1 : 0 result was on 16.04.13
  1 : 1 result was on 18.11.12
  ```